# General formula to generate the power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I wish to find the function that generates the following power series, I wonder if there exists one:

$1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^4}{4}-\dfrac{x^6}{6}+\dfrac{x^8}{8}...$

I know the series expansion for $\cos(x)$ is:

$1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^4}{4!}-\dfrac{x^6}{6!}+\dfrac{x^8}{8!}...$

But I don't know to transform this to obtain the first series.

Is there a way to find the generating function of a given power series? My guess is that not all power series have closed form to which they converge.

Comment: Hint:  its derivative is $-x+x^3-x^5+x^7-\cdots $.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}4-\frac{x^6}6+\cdots$, then $f'(x)=-x+x^3-x^5+\cdots=-\frac x{1+x^2}$. So, $f(x)=1-\log\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)$.

Comment: How did you manage to find the closed form so early? I understand that you differentiate the expression but how do you know the series is the representation of the function $-\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$? Is this just general experience or what?

Comment: @JamesWarthington It's something one learns to recognize pretty easily, but if you haven't seen it before, then of course it will seem mysterious. It's called a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: @JamesWarthington: It's geometric series with common ratio $-x^2$

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks, fixed

Comment: @Vasya: so how you manipulate $-x+x^3-x^5...$. By using this formula for geometric series? $S_n=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{(1-r)}$

Comment: @JamesWarthington $$\begin{align}-x+x^3-x^5+\cdots&=-x(1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots)\\&=-x(1+(-x^2)+(-x^2)^2+(-x^2)^3+\cdots)\\&=-x\times\frac1{1-(-x^2)}\\&=-\frac x{1+x^2}.\end{align}$$

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: In general, I expect it is harder to find the closed form of any given power series, am I correct?

Comment: @JamesWarthington Totally so! No doubt about that.